# I can't work out why I have strange page numbering at the start of my document?

Tags: page-numbering

I would like the following for my document:

I will use these abbreviations:

- wRn = with roman page number
- wAn = with Arabic page number
- Em = empty

---

- Cover page (Em)
- back cover page (Em)
- Abstract (wRn) I
- TOC (Em) - also not included with TOC (e.g. contents   3)
- LOF (wRn) II
- LOT (wRn) IV
- Abbreviations page (wRn) VI
- Introduction (wAn) 1

....with empty pages inbetween to make sure content starts on right page...

I really can't find a way to do this, I currently have no page number for the Abstract page, contents listed in table of contents and random roman page numbers for the rest....

I tried removing things at different place and attempted to rebuild this part of my document from scratch but to no luck. here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage[automark,clines]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\begin{document}
\sloppy
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.


\textsc{\Large text}\\[1.5cm]

% Title

\vspace{2cm}

{ \LARGE \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{0.5cm}

{ \large \bfseries Topic of Thesis: text \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{2cm}

{ \Large \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{1cm}

\textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{1cm}

\textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize Hamburg, \today}\\[0.5cm]

\newpage\

\thispagestyle{empty}\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{0.5cm}

{ \large \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{2cm}

\vspace{11.5cm} 

\textsc{\large 1. Reviewer: text*}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large 2. Reviewer: text*}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{1cm} 

\textsc{\footnotesize *text}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}

\abstract

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

{\newgeometry{left=0.98in,right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.5in}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\null\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\listoffigures\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\listoftables\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhead[R]{Introduction}\fancyhead[L]{Chapter 1}

%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyhead[ER]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[OL]{\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\thepage}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\chapter*{Abbreviations}

\upshape\noindent\Large\bfseries{General}


\vspace{0.5cm}

\upshape\noindent\Large\bfseries{estimates} 

\vspace{0.5cm}




\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

%\KOMAoption{footsepline}{:.5\textwidth}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Can someone see where I may be going wrong?

Comment: I've tried to format your lists but I'm not sure I understood them correctly. Since these are essential to your target format, please check and correct them so people can easily understand your question. I've also added `\end{document}` to your code but it would be helpful if you would make your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which is not cluttered by irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Your preamble is a mess. You are loading multiple, incompatible packages all of which are trying to configure the same aspects of your document. On top of that, you are also trying to configure the same formatting elements manually. This is bound to lead to trouble. I started trying to work through it but I realised that I just can't tell what you are trying to do so I don't know how to modify the code appropriately. Also, the `titlepage` environment is designed for use on a single page but yours spans 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a beginning. `tocbibind` is probably responsible for the Contents entry in the ToC since it is one of the advertised features of that package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
% don't load epstopdf at all - graphicx will handle things automatically
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}% better than setting baselineskip manually
  \onehalfspacing
\usepackage{nextpage}
\newcounter{savedpage}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
%   \sloppy% don't do this - it will undermine the typesetting of your entire document
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
      % Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
      % only works if a paragraph has started.
      \textsc{\Large text}\\[1.5cm]

      % Title
      \vspace{2cm}

      { \LARGE \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

      \vspace{0.5cm}

      { \large \bfseries Topic of Thesis: text \\[0.4cm] }

      \vspace{2cm}

      { \Large \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

      \vspace{1cm}

      \textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]
      \textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]

      \vspace{1cm}

      \textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
      \textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
      \textsc{\normalsize Hamburg, \today}\\[0.5cm]
    \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}
  \cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
  \begin{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    { \large \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

    \vfill

    \textsc{\large 1. Reviewer: text*}\\[0.5cm]
    \textsc{\large 2. Reviewer: text*}\\[0.5cm]

    \vspace{1cm}

    \textsc{\footnotesize *text}

  \end{center}
  \cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \begin{abstract}
    Abstract text here.\thispagestyle{plain}
  \end{abstract}
  \cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]
  {\newgeometry{left=0.98in,right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.5in}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\null\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

    \listoffigures\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

    \listoftables\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf[rh]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
    \fancyhf[lh]{\nouppercase\leftmark}

    \clearpage

    \chapter*{Abbreviations}

    \noindent{\upshape\Large\bfseries General\par}% \bfseries is a switch - it doesn't take an argument

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \noindent{\upshape\Large\bfseries estimates\par}

    \vspace{0.5cm}

    \cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{empty}]%
    \pagenumbering{arabic}%
    \chapter{Introduction}

    \thepage \arabic{page}

    some text\clearpage some more text

\end{document}
```

Note that you ought not to be manually changing things like `\section` and `\paragraph` if you are using `titlesec` else there is little point in loading the package. `fancyhdr` and `titlesec` are not incompatible but you might be better advised to use the page layout options offered by `titlesec`'s cousin, `titleps`, since those packages are designed to play nicely together. Or, drop `titlesec` if you are not using it anyway (as seems to be the case).

I am assuming that you do not really want the list of figures to be on a page labelled `II` since that would make no sense at all given that the ToC comes between the abstract and the list of figures. I'm guessing the contents should be on iii (unlabelled), the LoF on iv (labelled), LoT on v (labelled), abbreviations on vi (labelled) but you can obviously adjust to suit.

If you are just using `tocbibind` to add the bibliography to the ToC, you would probably be better off just doing that by hand using `\addcontentsline` rather than trying to disable 95% of the functionality of `tocbibind`.